# Is there a jquery plugin similar to Excel layout?

Tags: jquery, excel

can you tell me if  there is a jquery plugin similar to Excel layout, and I can merge or split cells on web page using it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
http://www.gelsheet.org/demo

Comment: thank you ,I will try it . does it have such feature as saving data to database?

Comment: Yes it includes php backend files